# How to extract a full table which loads further when scrolled down?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the maximum available historical price from a site which will load more information into the table as you scroll down the page. This code which I am currently using will only extract the first 100 lines.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Sub pullhistoricalprice()

    Dim xmlpage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long

    xmlpage.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=345400200&period2=1561046400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d", False
    xmlpage.send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText
    htmldoc.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 100
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    With htmldoc.body
        Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        For lngTable = 2 To objTable.Length - 2
            For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
        Next lngTable
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which column of the table does that come from? Also, you are extracting more than one value in your code whereas max should be a single value, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can take whatever the current cookie is that is given by pressing the download button then pass that in a request with WinHttp for the file which you then download by binary download.

Cookie is in headers of recorded request (dev tools - press F12 to open, go to network tab press download) - find request made and see cookie

[image]

In theory it may be possible to extract this cookie via a prior request. Otherwise, this code made only be a time-based solution subject to cookie expiry date.

```
Public Sub Test()
    DownloadFile "C:\Users\User\Desktop\", "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=345400200&period2=1561046400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=gdzXUTfT0l/"
End Sub
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal downloadFolder As String, ByVal downloadURL As String) As String
    Dim http As Object, tempArr As Variant
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    http.Open "GET", downloadURL, False
    http.setrequestheader "cookie", "B=bujjnjpeetmah; APID=UP86674562-8245-11e9-8433-020167e61c30; PRF=t%3DAAPL%252BASLN%252BA; GUCS=AQBqKRDM; GUC=AQABAQFdDhdd3UImCwVo&s=AQAAADRx8bGn&g=XQzIlw"
    http.send
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write http.responseBody
        .SaveToFile downloadFolder & "data.csv", 2  '< "/" on enter of downloadFolder. 2 for overwrite which is Ok if no file modifications.
        .Close
    End With
    DownloadFile = downloadFolder & tempArr
    Exit Function
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
    DownloadFile = vbNullString
End Function
```